# Swift UIcollectionView change content of second UICollectionView on same ViewController?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I’m new to collection views and I’m struggling to get a collection views selected cell to change the content of another collection views displayed content which both collection views are on same ViewController.

I have two working collection views on one view controller and want my selection on first collection view to change the content of the second collection view.

Didn’t feel I need to post my code of collectionViews as I set up the collectionViews like normal, as per Apple documentation.

So both collection views work, just this requested function doesn’t yet.

An example of the data would be:

Collection view one

```
Let arrayDrinks = [“beer”, “spirit”, “wine”]
```

Collection view two ( changes depending what is selected in collection view one)

```
Let arrayBeer = [“Carling”, “fosters”, “Carlsberg”]
Let arraySpirit = [“vodka”, “whiskey”]
Let arrayWine = [“red wine”, “white wine”, rose]
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Implement the collection view's delegate method.

```
extension YourViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == firstCollectionView {
           // Identify the selected cell here and change in your second collection view accordingly. 
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to set the delegate in your viewcontroller:

```
firstCollectionView.delegate =  self 
secondCollectionView.delegate =  self
```